# Neutralize fork-bomb through ssh

Tags: ssh, security, forking

I have access to a server through SSH (namely, it's our informatics server :) ) and ran a fork-bomb there (the bash one). Is there a way to neutralize it remotely? Just using `ssh name@server` does just nothing: no lines are output, even the password request, but `ping server` reaches it. Of course, the bomb will be eliminated tomorrow, but it would be nice if it's possible to do this myself...

Comment: Your server is somewhat busy now and it takes some time until other logins get some cpu time. Try logging in as root, maybe this id gets access earlier.

Comment: Even when I write `ssh root@server`, nothing happens (no password request). And even if it would be possible, I have no root access.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't even log in, then there's probably not much you can do.  As [explained on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#Defusing):

> Due to their nature, fork bombs can be difficult to stop once started.
>   Stopping a fork bomb from reproducing further requires the termination
>   of all running copies, which can be difficult to achieve. One problem
>   faced is that a separate program to terminate the fork bomb cannot
>   execute if the process table is fully saturated. The second major
>   problem is that in the time taken between finding the processes to
>   terminate and actually terminating them, more may have been created.